# Python - script hangs on open() function

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, subprocess, sys, hostapd

I have a Python script that first kills all `hostapd` processes then starts a fresh one. I want to capture the output of the `hostapd` start command to determine if it returns `AP-ENABLED` or `AP-DISABLED` so I decided to write it to a temporary file then read it.

However `open()` hangs indefinitely, or until I use ctrl-c; the program does not exit, but instead pukes out the output I expected:

```
Line #0: Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf


Line #1: Failed to create interface mon.wlan0: -95 (Operation not supported)


Line #2: wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE


Line #3: wlan0: Could not connect to kernel driver


Line #4: Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr b8:27:eb:35:34:de and ssid "Coriolis"


Line #5: random: Only 6/20 bytes of strong random data available from /dev/random


Line #6: random: Not enough entropy pool available for secure operations


Line #7: WPA: Not enough entropy in random pool for secure operations - update keys later when the first station connects


Line #8: wlan0: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->ENABLED


Line #9: wlan0: AP-ENABLED
```

Code:

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys


def start_hostapd():
    # kill any existing hostapd process 
    subprocess.call(['killall', 'hostapd'])

    # start new hostapd process 
    os.system('hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf > ./hostapd.log')

    # capture the output
    line_num = 0
    with open('hostapd.log', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            print('\nLine #{}: {}'.format(line_num, line))
            line_num += 1
            # sys.stdout.flush()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_hostapd()
```

I tried adding `sys.stdout.flush()` but to no avail.

Comment: Isn't `os.system('hostapd ...` calling deamon process ? and Its hangs here because it waits for exit code and because it's demon it doesn't finish  and it waits and waits? I guess You should use `os.popen` because it doesnt make implicit wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so I will explain You why You have problem here.

So `hostapd` is daemon process (Look at the last **d** in the name, most linux daemons have it).

So You are trying to start this daemon with the `os.system`. In the documentation I have checked that this function spawns and returns the process **return code**.
But to get the return code the `os.system` must wait for the daemon to finish. 
So that's why it hangs here.

As a solution. I suggest spawning the daemon with some no waiting function, like `os.spawn` with the `os.P_NOWAIT` flag.

Comment: I will try this and report back

Comment: `os.spawn` did not work but `os.spawnl` seems to return the lines immediately. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the `flush = True` to the print function, maybe it works like that